# Folding Bike Seat Post Replacement

Tags: saddle, seatpost, folding-bicycle

I have a folding bike ([basically this Origin8 model](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcRQUAODRIYErrFCwiVNwCAE0giH2nmp2Gx_79TmqLtm4Twr2hvngg)) and the seat/seat post got stolen.

I haven't replaced a seat post before, but [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007Q4M678) is the only replacement post I could find, and I'm not sure what else I need besides a saddle.  It doesn't have any sort of mounting apparatus, so I'm not sure what kind of saddle I need or if I'm missing really important hardware.  Is there a specific seat I should be looking for or do I need to buy mounting hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a separate saddle clamp, that clamps round the top of the post and the rails of a standard saddle, something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Saddle-Clamp-Straight-Seatposts-Silver/dp/B00718WE7G).

See also http://sheldonbrown.com/saddles.html#seatpost

http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/seatposts.html (scroll down to 'Traditional "pipe type" seatposts, use with separate saddle clamp'.)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a "seatpost shim" that converts you folding bike's seat tube inner diameter to a different inner diameter.  That way you would open up options for buying a better/different seatpost that actually has a modern clamp (mounting apparatus) at the top.

Your linked replacement says that post has an outer diameter (OD) of 34.1mm and 550mm long.

Maybe one of these ["Wheels Manufacturing" shims](http://wheelsmfg.com/seat-post-shims.html) could fit to convert it.  There is one listed that is slightly off: it is listed as 34.0mm taking it down to either 27.2mm or 30.9mm.

Then, for example, there are [27.2mm diameter seatposts that are 400mm long](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000G8LQYK) that include the clamp apparatus at the top.

(I have not tried this setup before, so do not know it will work.  Also, if the 400mm long seatpost would be too short, then this clearly won't work out for you.  If you had the original seatpost pushed down much more than 150mm / 6 inches then it should work.  It is a big difference between 400mm and 550mm.)